# How to write each row of a spark dataframe to different Hive tables (using Scala)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a spark dataframe as shown below. The first column contains the content of Party text file (read using sc.wholeTextfile). Second row contains the content of Identifier text file. Now, I have to loop through each row of the below dataframe and write into different hive tables. The first row should be written to Party table, second row should be written to Identifier table and so on.

When I loop through this dataframe using dataframe.foreaach, I can't use spark session as spark session is non-serializable.

```
+--------------------+--------------+
|             content|         TblNm|
+--------------------+--------------+
|DSP_ID|DSP_PARTY_...|         Party|
|DSP_ID|DSP_Party_...|    Identifier|
|DSP_ID|DSP_Party_...| Communication|
|DSP_ID|DSP_Party_...|    Individual|
|DSP_ID|DSP_Party_...|      Language|
|DSP_ID|DSP_Party_...|          Name|
|DSP_ID|DSP_Party_...| Certification|
|DSP_ID|DSP_Party_...|Classification|
|DSP_Id|DSP_Party_...|  Organization|
|DSP_ID|DSP_Party_...|       Address|
|DSP_Id|DSP_Party_...|     Specialty|
|DSP_ID|Parent_DSP...|  Relationship|
|DSP_ID|DSP_Party_...|          Role|
+--------------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

cache the dataframe and use N df.write... statements - with filters.

And indeed serializable means Spark does not work this way as you note for tables using spark session for Hadoop, for jdbc to mysql, etc. you can use foreach, etc. but not via df.write.